# AngularJS - pass a controller variable into custom ng-repeat filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to make that expression work :

```
   <li ng-repeat="row in reservationCtrl.rows |rowRangeFilter:1:reservationCtrl.rowCount" class="row row--1">
 {{row}} </li>
```

How I can pass a variable from controller, dynamically defined before redirection to view to my filter declaration? Currently my controller variable is ignored in expression no matter where I put it.

Filter:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('airline').filter('rowRangeFilter', rowRangeFilter);

    function rowRangeFilter() {
          return function(items, begin, end) {                                     

                return items.slice( begin, end);
            }
    }
})();
```

Comment: What's not working? Any errors...?

Comment: Where's your controller?

Comment: Looks like your code works http://jsfiddle.net/SNF9x/285/ so the problem is in your controller probably. Share its code